# Download bulk citation data for pre grant USPTO patents

Tags: pre-grant, citation, bulk-download

Where can I download bulk data for citations that come from pre grant patent publications? I tried to find it in the USPTO bulk data page and also on PatentsView but no luck. I am sure I'm missing something here so any direction would be great here. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Lens? https://www.lens.org/lens/search/patent/structured Also, by citations do you mean the number of citations or a list of the actual document?

Comment: list of the actual documents

Comment: I tried a quick test with Lens and got at least some of the citations exported. This is not my specialty, but you might try it and see how it goes with your search.

Comment: You want the bulk data (or some set of fields) for a particular set of documents that are cited by a published application?